# xml problem with php

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to use an xml file and retrieve all links from it.  so far I have:

```
$xmlHeadline = $xml->channel[0]->item[3]->link;
print($xmlHeadline);
```

This works ok to print the single headline link for `item[3]` in the xml.  But as you can see it is 2 levels deep.  Then next one will be at `channel[0]->item[4]->link`.  There is no channel 1, just `channel[0]`.

All the examples on the internet only deal with 1 level deep.  They all used a `foreach` loop, but I am not sure if that can be used here...

How can I cycle through all item's in the xml and echo all links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
foreach ($xml->channel[0]->item as $item) {
    echo $item->link;
}
```

or

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('/channel/item/link') as $link) {
    echo $link;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a DOM parser, that will allow you to load the xml as a structured hierarchy and then use a function like `getElementById` http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php to parse the xml and get the specific items you want at any depth.

If you provide the structure of the xml file I may be able to help with the specific use of a DOM function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '<channels><channel>
<item><link>google.com</link></item>
<item><link>google.com.cn</link></item>
<item><link>google.com.sg</link></item>
<item><link>google.com.my</link></item>
</channel></channels>';
$xml  = simplexml_load_string($str);
$objs = $xml->xpath('//channel/item/link');
```

**PS:** Please include some example of your xml